# Load event ending when accessing external file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, onload-event

When creating a new form I have the following code for the new form's load event.

```
    private void Card_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name = variables.filename; //File name
        this.Text = name; //Form name
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(name); 
        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Card");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            txt1.Text = xn["option1"].InnerText;
            txt2.Text = xn["option2"].InnerText;
            txt3.Text = xn["option3"].InnerText;
            txt4.Text = xn["option4"].InnerText;
            txt5.Text = xn["option5"].InnerText;
        }
    }
```

My problem is that when it gets to `xml.Load` it leaves the load event and goes back to creating the form meaning that the rest of the code doesn't get used. I assume this is the same for other types of file handling because the same happens when I use `File.ReadLines`. 
This is the code I use to create the form.

```
    Card frm1 = new Card();
    frm1.Show();
```

And this is the xml file I am using

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Card>
        <option1>123</option1>
        <option2>456</option2>
        <option3>654</option3>
        <option4>321</option4>
        <option5>246</option5>
    </Card>
```

Comment: What about an exception? don't you get one?  do you catch it somewhere?

Comment: It doesn't give any exception. And I'm not sure how to use catch statements properly so I usually don't.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that there is no exception? (please use try-catch, dont rely on a program crash). Event handlers are not necessarily affecting the rest of the program when an exception is thrown. It's nothing personal, but it's happening a lot that a possible cause is commented, denied by the asker and later discovered to be the problem after all, so please triple-check this.

Comment: Please elaborate on _"it leaves the load event and goes back to creating the form"_. Explain very explicitly which behavior _exactly_ you're seeing and how you determine that claim to be the cause. For all we know, you're loading an XML with an empty "Card" list, so the `foreach()` never actually enumerates, and your textboxes remain empty, and you think the textboxes being empty means your code not executing. Place breakpoints and step through your code. This has nothing to do with files anyway, that's the beauty of abstraction. Files don't suddenly change C#'s or .NET's rules.

Comment: Stepping through the code shows that it reaches the line xml.load is on then  going one more step returns to the other form. It doesn't reach the forloop, its as if it thinks the load event has ended.

Comment: As you commented you don't know how to use catch statement properly: for debugging, it is enough to write `try { /* your code */ } catch (Exception e) { throw; }` and then set a breakpoint on the `catch` opening bracket, so you will always know when any exception is thrown and you can inspect `e` in the debugger.

Comment: Thank you for telling me this, I managed to find what the problem was and fix it.